# SQL split values on multiple rows

Tags: sql

I made a select and it looks like this

```
SELECT name,class_name
FROM students
INNER JOIN classes on classes.id = students.id
```

and I get a table like

```
| name     | class_name     |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Daniel   | Math           |
| Johnny   | Physics        |
| Johnny   | Math           |
| Andrew   | English        |
...
```

How am I supposed to split the table to get the first two classes each student attends (students can attend more than two classes or a single class)

Example:

```
| name     | class_1        | class_2  |
| -------- | -------------- | ---------|
| Daniel   | Math           |          |
| Johnny   | Math           | Physics  |
| Andrew   | English        |          |
...
```

I was thinking of transposing the table, however, I don't know how to actually do it or if it's a good approach.

Comment: Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: @Abra I tried outer joining, however, I get random nulls. https://prnt.sc/11sx179 If I use inner join I get the same table as before.

Comment: I think you need a dynamic pivot here. Please tag your product here as it differs from product o product.

Comment: Hello @Radush - thanks for your question - are you able to clarify "first two classes" - is that alphabetical, order in which they appear in the source, Is there another column on the classes table that shows the "order" - such as a unique key, or a rank?

Comment: @irnerd There's no other column and the table isn't sorted in any way. The first two classes that appear in the source must be inserted in each column.

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated every different class for each student in a single column with commas as separators (because classes can contain spaces, for example, "Computer Science") then I split the single column into the two required classes.

```
WITH part
     AS (SELECT NAME,
                class_name
         FROM   students
                INNER JOIN classes
                        ON classes.id = students.id),
     ans
     AS (SELECT NAME,
                Array_to_string(Array_agg(class_name), ',') AS cl
         FROM   part
         GROUP  BY NAME)
SELECT NAME,
       Split_part(cl, ',', 1) AS class_1,
       Split_part(cl, ',', 2) AS class_2
FROM   ans
```